# How to merge two objects based on varying indices

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I've got two objects in an array returned from an API endpoint that exposes elected officials based on locale. One is `offices` and the other is `officials`. I need to understand how to merge these two objects into one that makes more sense.

```
{
  "offices": [
    {
      "name": "President of the United States",
      "officialIndices": [0]
    }, {
      "name": "Vice-President of the United States",
      "officialIndices": [1]
    }, {
      "name": "United States Senate",
      "officialIndices": [2, 3]
    }, {
      "name": "Governor",
      "officialIndices": [4]
    }
  ],
  "officials": [
    {
      "name": "Donald J. Trump"
    }, {
      "name": "Mike Pence"
    }, {
      "name": "Dianne Feinstein"
    }, {
      "name": "Kamala D. Harris"
    }, {
      "name": "Edmund G. Brown Jr.",
    }
  ]
}
```

My end goal would look like this:

```
[
  "officials": [
    {
      "name": "Donald J. Trump",
      "office": "President of the United States"
    }, {
      "name": "Mike Pence",
      "office": "Vice-President of the United States"
    }, {
      "name": "Dianne Feinstein",
      "office": "United States Senate"
    }, {
      "name": "Kamala D. Harris",
      "office": "United States Senate",
    }, {
      "name": "Edmund G. Brown Jr.",
      "office": "Governor"
    }
  ]
}
```

So this is my failed attempt.

```
var representatives = data;

function addOffice(name, indices){
  _.forEach(indices, function(value, key) {
    representatives.officials[key].office = name;
  });
}

_.forEach(representatives.offices, function(value, key) {
  // console.log("Office: '" + value.name + "' should be applied to officials " + value.officialIndices);
  addOffice(value.name, value.officialIndices);
});

// remove `offices` as it's now redundant
delete representatives.offices;

console.log(representatives);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var offices = dataObj['offices'];
var officials = dataObj['officials'];
var mergedArray = {officials : []};

offices.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    var indices = obj['officialIndices'];
    indices.forEach(function(indice, ind) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj['name'] = officials[indice]['name'];
        newObj['office'] = obj['name'];
        mergedArray['officials'].push(newObj);
    })
})

// mergedArray is your answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
function addOffice(obj) {
  return {
    officials : obj.officials.map(function(official, idx){
      return {
        name : official.name,
        office : obj.offices.filter(function(office) {
          return office.officialIndices.indexOf(idx) > -1
        })[0].name
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that like this:

```
obj.officials.map(function(item, i){
  var j = 0;
  for (j in obj.offices)
  {
    if (obj.offices[j].officialIndices.includes(i)) {
        break;
    }
  }
  return {
    "name": item.name,
    "office": obj.offices[j].name
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) to flatten the result of `officials` taken from using [pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) in an office's `officialIndices`. Lastly, we use [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to transform the resulting value of all `officials` with their associated `office`.

```
var result = _.flatMap(data.offices, function(office) {
  return _(data.officials)
    .pick(office.officialIndices)
    .map(function(official) {
      return _(official)
        .pick('name')
        .set('office', office.name)
        .value();
    }).value();
});
```

```js
var data = {
  "offices": [{
    "name": "President of the United States",
    "officialIndices": [0]
  }, {
    "name": "Vice-President of the United States",
    "officialIndices": [1]
  }, {
    "name": "United States Senate",
    "officialIndices": [2, 3]
  }, {
    "name": "Governor",
    "officialIndices": [4]
  }],
  "officials": [{
    "name": "Donald J. Trump"
  }, {
    "name": "Mike Pence"
  }, {
    "name": "Dianne Feinstein"
  }, {
    "name": "Kamala D. Harris"
  }, {
    "name": "Edmund G. Brown Jr.",
  }]
};

var result = _.flatMap(data.offices, function(office) {
  return _(data.officials)
    .pick(office.officialIndices)
    .map(function(official) {
      return _(official)
        .pick('name')
        .set('office', office.name)
        .value();
    }).value();
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```